# Insert non conventional data into Sqite3 using Python

Tags: python, sqlite

I have tried a lot of different variations and debugging with just straight strings for the variables but I believe this has to do with the datatype? This was supposed to be a quick prototype but has eaten an afternoon already!

```
#! usr/bin/ python
import sqlite3 
import sys
import psutil

cpu_usage = psutil.cpu_percent()
ram_usage = psutil.phymem_usage()
disk_usage = psutil.disk_usage('/')
network = psutil.network_io_counters(True)

conn = sqlite3.connect('stats.db')
cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute("CREATE TABLE stats (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, cpu TEXT, ram TEXT, disk TEXT, network TEXT, timestamp DATE DEFAULT (datetime('now','localtime')))")
cur.execute("INSERT INTO stats (id, cpu, ram, disk, network, timestamp) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", (None, cpu_usage, ram_usage, disk_usage, network, None))

print(cur.fetchall()) 
conn.commit()

conn.close()
```

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "build_db.py", line 15, in <module>
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO stats (id, cpu, ram, disk, network, timestamp) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", (None, cpu_usage, ram_usage, disk_usage, network, None))
sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 2 - probably unsupported type.
```

Comment: Have you spent the time to look at your data yet?

Comment: Your problem is that `psutil.cpu_percent()` returns a `list` which isn't a datatype supported by SQLite.

Comment: yeah  Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams thats the first thing I thought - its definitely uncoventional data - I have tried a using different datatypes and parameter styles without success.

Comment: @DanD. ok - thats good to know but I am really looking for a solution to this.

Comment: What is the ouput of this: for var in (cpu_usage,ram_usage,disk_usage,network): print var,type(var)

Answer (score 0):

You really need to read the [documentation for psutil](http://code.google.com/p/psutil/wiki/Documentation#CPU).

> psutil.disk_usage(path)
>
> Return disk usage statistics about the given path as a namedtuple
>   including total, used and free space expressed in bytes plus the
>   percentage usage. OSError is raised if path does not exist. See
>   examples/disk_usage.py script providing an example usage.

```
>>> psutil.disk_usage('/')
usage(total=21378641920, used=4809781248, free=15482871808, percent=22.5)
```

Now its upto you to figure out which value you want to insert into the database.

Comment: This is why the question is referring to 'non conventional' data. I am aware of what psutil.disk_usage('/') returns.

Comment: If that is the case then you can also convert the value that you want into a string (which is the type you are inserting).

Answer (score 0):

I have made a workaround - it is not so elegant but I import simplejson and use the results of simplejson.dumps(variable) to insert value as json.